# Access to the Path Denial for my file operations, that I can't seem to fix

Tags: path, infopath2010, readonly

I am trying to construct a simple routine in VB 2010 Express (.Net Framework 4.5) that removes old files  from my nightly db backup folder. Whenever I try to set the ReadOnly state to false (to assure deletion can be done) or to Delete a file I get a "System.ArgumentException:Access to the path is denied" error.

I have been fighting this for two days and have rewritten the code multiple times, but always with the same results.  When I look at the properties for the designated file, everything looks perfect.

Here is an image of the properties . . .

**<< WOOPS- I'd love to have been able to post my image here to help, but it is not possible for a new post.  Hopefully this hand typed effort will suffice. >>**

```
_data              {Microsoft.Win32.Win32Native.WIN32_RLE_ATTRIBUTE_DATA}
_datalnitialised    0
Attributes  Archive {32}
CreationTime        #5/17/20131:57:45 AM*
CreationTimeUtc     #5/17/2013 5:57:45 AM#
Directory           {C:\powerhome\Database\dbAutoBaks}
DirectoryName       "C:\powerhome\Database\dbAutoBaks"
DisplayPath         "ph-130517.db"
ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED  5
Exists               True
Extension            ".db"
FullName             "C:\powerhome\Database\dbAutoBaks\ph-130517.db"
FullPath             "C:\powerhome\Database\dbAutoBaks\ph-130517.db"
IsReadOnly           False
LastAccessTime       #5/17/20131:57:45 AM#
```

Here is my Code . . .

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Security.AccessControl

Public Class phFileTrim

Private Sub fileTrim_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim text As String
    Dim UserAccount As String = "Administrators"
    Dim intdays As Integer = 30
    Dim folderPath As String = "C:\powerhome\Database\dbAutoBaks"
    Dim fi As IO.FileInfo = New IO.FileInfo(folderPath)

    'Check out System.IO.FileInfo Class tutorial

    For Each fi In New IO.DirectoryInfo(folderPath).GetFiles("*.*")
        Try
            fi.IsReadOnly = False
            If fi.Exists Then
                If (Now - fi.CreationTime).Days > intdays Then fi.Delete()
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            text = "File Delete Failed: " & ex.ToString
            MsgBox(text)
        End Try
    Next
    Me.Close()
End Sub
End Class
```

The error is triggered by either of the ***FileInfo.IsReadOnly = False*** or the ***FileInfo.Delete() operations***.

Looking at the debug property pop-up for the variables, I see that "fi" seems to be the issue.  All uses of it after definition seem to have a access denied=5 error.  Thus suspecting that I have formed the "Dim fi As IO.FileInfo = New IO.FileInfo(folderPath)" statement incorrectly.

Any thoughts would be GREATLY appreciated.  Doesn't seem like this should be rocket science, but I am sure missing something.

==Monday Morning ===

I just simplified everything and changed the complex "Dim fi As IO.FileInfo = New IO.FileInfo(folderPath)" to . . .

```
 Dim fi As New FileInfo("C:\powerhome\Database\dbAutoBaks\ph-130517.db")
```

This is the fully qualified path to a specific file that exists, yet I still get an access error when fi is Dimensioned.

The file is on the same computer as the VB code, but I am encountering this error when debugging.  I haven't tried running an executable of this program.  It would be in the powerhome directory when executed.

== Monday 9AM ===
Even this simple code throws an ACCESS_DENIED error 5. (And this is from the MSDN official library of examples!)

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)  Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim path1 As String = Path.GetTempFileName()
    Dim finfo As FileInfo = New FileInfo(path1)
End Sub
End Class
```

I have made sure that my app.manifest execution level is set to . . .

```
 <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

but still no success.

What in the world is blocking my file accesses?

:-(

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved.

The "ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED  5" property I was receiving when I executed the first "fi" code, was not an error at all. Apparently the ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED is a property of the 'fi' object just like IsReadOnly is.  The "5" indicates that "all is well".

When I first started debugging my routine and encountered a critical error on my dimensioning of fi, I saw the ACCESS_ERROR and assumed that was the problem.

Thru subsequent days of debugging, I kept trying to get rid of the ACCESS_ERROR without checking to see if my code was truly OK.

Somewhere along the line, my code became bug free and I never discovered that until another programmer suggested some trial code that he knew worked, and I still encountered the ACCESS_ERROR.

He pointed out that was not really an error, and when I tried my code it worked perfectly (but still with the ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED value of 5, which was OK).

I never found anything in the MSDN documentation that indicated what the values for ACCESS_ERROR can be.  The value of 5 was  listed in one document and I assumed that was an error value, when apparently it is not.